# Openvpn keep multiple connection with same username and password

Tags: debian, openvpn

I have configure my Open VPN. I can connect to it but my problem is when I use same username in 2 different device it always reconnect

the device 1 connected and device 2 reconnecting then after 1 second the device 1 reconnecting and device 2 is connected

but if I use 2 different username for every device it works fine no one get disconnected

is this possible to make 1 username and password for every device and the connection should be stable

Comment: But why would you want to share credentials? Why not one for each individual device?

Comment: for the sake of my exploration :) i am trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `duplicate-cn`

```
–duplicate-cn
Allow multiple clients with the same common name to concurrently connect. 
In the absence of this option, OpenVPN will disconnect a client instance upon
connection of a new client having the same common name.
```